# Can not access Grub on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 machine

Tags: grub2, bootloader

A month back I have installed nvidia driver from 'System Update>Additional Drivers' settings.
After that my Ubuntu logo splash screen became horrible and I edited grub and set the resolution to "1024x720 -24"

I don't know why, but after this I can not access Grub by pressing and holding Shift key anymore.
I have tried every possible method to install grub but I failed, nothing worked I can not reach the grub menu during boot.
I found a method to install grub from Live CD but also failed.

Methods I tried

Changing Hidden timeout

Using Boot repair tool (said can't be used in legacy, should boot live cd in UEFI mode)

Reinstalling grub from normal session. (sudo grub-install /dev/sda) 
Live CD grub repair selecting the Try Ubuntu option. 
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Please help I don't want to reinstall the OS again.

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And if UEFI fast boot on, then you probably do not have time to press any keys before system reboots. You need a full cold boot or shutdown, remove battery if laptop and all mains, hold power switch to drain any left over power, then  connect power & boot. IF UEFI then escape key usually gets you into grub menu. If still issues post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: I kept using shift because that's what it ways everywhere. Esc worked!